# Google Chart API Request Limits

Tags: charts, request, limit

Just want to know if there are any request limits for Google Chart API .

From one of the forum (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/google-chart-api/request$20limit/google-chart-api/OcgFN6vdFrc/kLILyz3xDuwJ) i found that there is no request limit for Google Visualization API (JS) ,  exception is GeoMap and GeoChart. So i believe if we just want to draw a chart , there is no limit on API request but it will be applied only when we integrate Visualization API with GeoMap and GeoChart.

I could also find that in (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-chart-api/4tSecsyQEHk/yKb9caU5PLUJ) saying Limit of '50,000' queries per user per day . Since its an old entry not sure whether this limit is still valid.

Thanks in advance.

Jijomon Thottungalthara.

Answer (score 1):

Google chart has no request limit, but keep in mind that google may apply limit if it sees some inappropriate activity or if multiple request are coming from single ip/user. This is written in terms of google API use.